# Measurement of any qubit state in Y-basis

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience

how can I measure any qubit state in Y-basis in qiskit. there is this solution here [How to measure in another basis](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/how-to-measure-in-another-basis) but it gives the qubit's position on bloch sphere in z-axis where as I think it should be on y-axis just like in X-measurement basis (created by H,Z-measure,H) the qubit position is always on x-axis.

The y-basis measurement in solution (link above) uses the initial state of |+⟩ and if we change the qubit initial state  to 0 or 1 it collapses onto z-axis whereas it should remain on y-axis , if it is correctly measuring in y-basis, right?

Any guidance about how we can measure in y-basis using qiskit would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A related thread https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11783/9459