# How can I prepare and measure spins in arbitrary directions in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

I'm just starting with Qiskit and I would like to reproduce basic results about spin measurements. For that I want to prepare multiple spins each in arbitrary directions and measure them in arbitrary directions to get the probabilities.

What is the suggested way to do that in Qiskit?

Comment: This question might be helpful.  It is not for *arbitrary* directions, but does show how to measure in the X-basis and Y-basis:  https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/how-to-measure-in-another-basis

Comment: Another useful reference might be this lab from the Qiskit textbook: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-labs/Lab02_QuantumMeasurement.html
It discusses why the measurement has to be done in the Z-basis and shows how to do some measurements.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested way to do measurements in a different axis is to change the orientation of the state vector at the end and measure in the $z$-basis as usual.

To go from one basis to the other you can use $H$ and $S=\sqrt{Z}$ gates that act as unitary transformations of your system. If you apply $H$ to your qubit and then do a measurement, it is the same as measuring in the $x$-axis. $HS^\dagger+$measurement is the same as measuring in the $y$-axis. A visual representation can be found in this answer: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13611/15775

If you need to do a measurement in any other basis you can use rotation gates $R_y(\theta),R_z(\theta)+$measurement (two rotation gates are enough to do all kind of rotations).

To prepare an arbitrary state, you can use `.initialize`. Alternatively, you can also use the rotation gates.

The details of the gate operations and arbitrary initialization in Qiskit can be found here:
https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.html