# How to measure different pauli matrices?

Tags: qiskit, measurement

I have a system of two qubit interacting and I would like to do 4 measurement, qubit A and qubit B before interaction and qubit A and B after the interaction, now i would like to measure different direction of spin, for example i would like to measure $\sigma_X$ for A and $\sigma_Y$ for B; is there in qiskit a function like `measure(A, ...)` where you can specify the direction of measurement or the measurment operator?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're simply asking how to measure in different bases in Qiskit. There's no native way to do it, but it is very easy to do, see for example here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13605/how-to-measure-in-another-basis